# Third cohomology of a group

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, reference-works

I'm familiar with two primary ways to discuss the n$^{th}$ cohomology of groups with coefficients in an abelian group $A$:

(1) Through the exploration of n-fold extensions.

(2) By examining the map $d_n: C^n(G, A) \to C^{n+1}(G, A)$.

Many references I've encountered predominantly focus on the second approach for deriving cohomology. When it comes to utilizing the first method involving extensions, most discussions seem to be limited to n=2. I'm particularly interested in understanding the $\textbf{third cohomology}$ of a group via extensions. However, I'm struggling to find a comprehensive reference on this topic. Could you provide insights or direct me to appropriate $\textbf{references}$?

Comment: The classical interpretation of $H^3(G,M)$ is by ${\rm Ext}^2(G,M)$ of equivalence classes of crossed module extensions of $G$ with $M$. See for example [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2861). In general, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017142/is-there-an-interpretation-of-higher-cohomology-groups-in-terms-of-group-extensi).